# SharePoint REST api /CSOM to get the details of inactive features in Site and Web

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom, sharepoint-online, office365-restapi

I need to access the feature details of web and site which is not activated using the REST api or by using CSOM.Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible. Using CSOM you can only get a list of *activated* features for your site. The [`Feature`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.feature.aspx) class in this case contains `DisplayName` and `DefinitionId` properties.

To get features via CSOM you can use following to get information on activated web scope features:

```
var webFeatures = ctx.Web.Features;
ctx.Load(webFeatures,fcol => fcol.Include(f => f.DisplayName,f => f.DefinitionId));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(var f in webFeatures)
{
   Console.WriteLine(f.DisplayName);
}
```

Since this is o365 SSOM is rather not an option.

Comment: I tried the same but feature doesn't have the property DisplayName

Comment: Have you loaded properties explicitly as in the snippet above?